# Converting string into dictionary appending special characters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have a string which contains `JSON` array. I am mapping that string with a key in a dictionary. Doing this adds the **"/"** in the string. Again, I'm converting that string further into NSData. Please help me out.

Code to generate Json String:

```
int i = 0;

NSMutableArray *contacts = [NSMutableArray array];
for (i = 0; i < all_contacts.count; i++) {
  [contacts addObject:@{@"phone" : all_contacts[i]}];
}

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:contacts
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];
if (!jsonData) {
  //error here
} else {
  NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

**Before** converting string to NSDictionary

```
[{"phone":5555648583},{"phone":5554787672},{"phone":952365285},{"phone":5555228243},{"phone":5557664823},{"phone":5556106679}]
```

**After** converting to NSDictionary

```
{
    key = "[{\"phone\":5555648583},{\"phone\":5554787672},{\"phone\":952365285},{\"phone\":5555228243},{\"phone\":5557664823},{\"phone\":5556106679}]";
}
```

I want to convert NSDictionary into NSData without appending "/" characters?

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The backslash characters are actually inserted for presentation only. If you type `po jsonString` in the console, you will verify there aren't any.